# Group action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I am working on an exercise in group cohomology and need the following result.

Prove that there is a unique group action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

I think what's confusing me most is that I believe I found two group actions, the trivial action and the following

$\alpha:\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2 \; \; \ni \alpha(0,0) = 0, \; \alpha(0,1) = 1, \; \alpha(1,0) = 1, \; \alpha(1,1) = 0$

Is this action somehow isomorphic to the trivial action? If so, how can I see that?

Comment: Obviously you are right that there are two actions. Where is the exercise from?

Comment: I believe that my professor wrote this exercise. It must be a typo then.

Comment: Maybe what is meant is that there is a unique nontrivial group action?

Comment: I reached out to get some clarification. We are considering the group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acting on the group $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  An action of a group H on a group A is a
group homomorphism from H to Aut(A), where Aut(A) is the group of
automorphisms of the group A.  If $A=\mathbb{Z}/2$, then since an automorphism
takes the identity to itself, and since an automorphism is a bijection,
there's only one possibility for an automorphism of A, and hence for an
action (the trivial one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is about an action of a group on an (abelian) group through group automorphisms. The way the question was worded was potentially confusing but I suspect it came from a context where the intention was clear. Group cohomology is mostly about situations where you have chain complexes of abelian groups with actions of a group by automorphisms (having said that, there are some situations where abelian groups are replaced by groups ore even sets).

A similar situation could occur with the expression a group action on a ring - the intention would almost certainly be that it was an action through ring automorphisms.

But if/when in doubt check!